# How can I cancel the use of a tactical insertion in Black Ops

Tags: call-of-duty-black-ops

In certain game modes (e.g. Demolition) in Black Ops I might use the Tactical Insertion equipment to spawn closer to the objective.

If an opponent catches me dropping that tactical insertion beacon they will often camp out and wait for an easy kill when I re-spawn right in front of them.

How can I cancel spawning on the tactical insertion?

The forum post [Why I am not as worried about Tac Insert as you](http://www.callofduty.com/board/viewtopic.php?f=70&t=273054&p=3261277&sid=vp7sajfq65mkcs1v3f1o56l1v6#p3261277) implies it is possible in the killcam but I don't recall seeing the option.

> Trying to use Tac Insert but are getting Tac Insert spawned camped? Well, you probably deserve that but you can now cancel your own Tac Insert in the Killcam. That's new to Black Ops.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a prompt on the kill cam that says the Y button to cancel tactical insertion (assuming xbox 360), but I've not been completely successful in getting it to work.

A quick google showed a few other people complaining about the same issue.

Comment: I tried it out last night in a demolition game and it worked fine. While watching the killcam the additional option appeared below the re-spawn option. On PS3 it is triangle to cancel the tactical insertion and square to re-spawn.

Comment: @FishOfPrey I haven't tried it since the last big update so hopefully it is fixed.